# Calling in C++ a non member function inside a class with a method with the same

Tags: c++, c

I have this class with an instance method named **open** and need to call a function declared in C also called **open**. Follows a sample:

```
void SerialPort::open()
{
    if(_open)
        return;
    fd = open (_portName.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY ); 
    _open = true;
}
```

When I try to compile it (using GCC) I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'SerialPort::open(const char*, int)'
```

I included all the required C headers. When I change the name of the method for example **open2** I don't have not problems compiling.

How can I solve this problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid starting your names with "_".

Comment: Don't see why? And it's very handy for member variables.

Comment: It's a point of the standard: most identifiers begining with `_` are reserved. The exact list is a bit complicated. It goes something like: including 2 consecutive `_`, begining by `_` followed by a upper case, etc... and since you're not likely to memorize the exact list, it's just best to avoid it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Call

```
fd = ::open(_portName.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
```

The double colon (`::`) before the function name is C++'s [scope resolution operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator):

> If the resolution operator is placed
>   in front of the variable name then the
>   global variable is affected.

Comment: But that doesn't work if you don't know which namespace open is in. For example, if you rely on the namespace of the first argument for the compiler to find the right one.

Answer (score 8):

Write `::open` instead of `open`. The `::` prefix indicates that the name should be taken from the global scope. (Global namespace? I'm not certain about its exact meaning, to be honest...)

Answer (score 4):

add **"::"** before  `open (_portName.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

1) You are using namespace resolution if calling function and function being called are in different namespaces, including parent namespace

2) If your calling function is defined above function being called declare the function before caller function.
eg:

```
 void bar();

 void foo()
 {
  bar();
 }

void bar()
{
 ....
}
```